# What happened to the remaining Inglourious Basterds members?

Tags: ending, inglourious-basterds

As we know the original squad of the basterds was 8 soldiers and Lt. Raine so that makes 9 people. Later in France they added the german Hugo Stiglitz to their squad making 10 of them. (We can see for a fact that still all 9 were alive when they rescued Stiglitz). Lt. Hickox makes no. 11 before the meeting prior to the Operation Kino.

> Now we also know that Lt. Hickox, Stiglitz and Wicki die in the cellar at that meeting. 
>  Lt. Raine and Utivich are captured by Landa. Donny and Omar die in the cinema.

So that makes 7 whose fate we know and 4 not accounted for.

We can see at least two soldiers of the 4 still alive prior to the operation Kino event (Hirshberg and one more) - in the scene at the vet where Lt. Raine talks to Bridgett von Hammersmark after the cellar incident.

So my question is: What happened to these 4 soldiers, is it ever addressed? (Bonus material or interviews with Tarantino perhaps)

Comment: I like to think they are still wandering Europe, killin' Nazis.

Comment: Plot twist : they end up chilling together with Hans on the island he bargained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this article from [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/inglourious-basterds-movie-team-members-what-happened/) it states that

> In the original script, however, Hirschberg (played by Samm Levine) survived and he, along with other unspecified Basterds, reunited with Raine and Utivich after settling things with Landa.

However as this is not in the final script and there has been no other word on this, it is ultimately up to interpretation.